# MS Word: replacing space *before* string found via regex

Tags: regex, ms-word, notepad++

Good people, Long time listener, first time caller here.

I have found ample help on the "search" side of my problem but I am stuck on the replace. Example:

> hello 9
>
> world 18
>
> howdy 37

By using " ([0-9])([0-9])" - with a space and as many ([0-9]) as needed - I can easily find a number preceded by a space.

I want to replace that space with semicolon to get:

> hello;9
>
> world;18

etc. I can't remove all space in the text and replace it with ";". So the question is:

How do I tell MS Word - or perhaps notepad++ - to use the found string to remove its space without replacing the found numbers?

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Word, using wildcards, place the different parts in "expressions" - parentheses. So in order to find [space]number with any number of digits:

```
( )([0-9]{1;})
```

And then replace it with semicolon plus the second expression:

```
;\2
```

The backslash denotes an expression, followed by the index number of the expression. You can include multiple expressions BTW.

Note that the definition of the number of characters - {1;} - contains a *delimiter* (list separator). Depending on the Windows system configuration, this might not be a semi-colon. It could be a comma, or another character. In the Windows Control Panel (for Win 7): Region and Language/Formats/Additional Settings/List Separator. Programmatically, this can be read from the Registry.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. This sounds very promising but when I follow your steps, it says "the find what text contains a pattern match expression which is not valid" and googling that has not quite hit the mark. Any tips?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention that. It depends on your system set-up, whether a comma or a semi-colon is considered the "delimiter". For me, it's a semi-colon, so I was getting the message you quote before I changed from a comma. Change the semi-colon to a comma: {1,}. I'll add that to my Answer.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Now it works. Thank you so so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Notepad++ with replace option:

```
Find what: (?<=[a-zA-Z])\s(?=[0-9]+)
Replace with: ;
```

I'm basically just looking for spaces with letters in front, and numbers after.

Comment: You're all kinds of terrific. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will just add my experience with world wild card with that of Cindy Meister's answer.

While working with huge data and long regex You should use the larger, precise regex string to get exact replacement you want, while not capturing the group that are not required.

In your case you should use `([A-Z]{1,}) ([0-9]{1,2})` to replace with `\1;\2`

No need to capture the group (space in your case) which you are removing anyway.

here ([0-9]{1,2}) should be set according to occurrences of numbers. In your example you have showed 1 or 2 occurrences.